# How do I put a button A under button B such that the left side of A is vertically aligned with the center of B?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

How do I position a button that starts vertically aligned with the middle of another button above it? The size of the upper button may vary from screen to screen.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do u have a sketch or something to make it clear?

Comment: I tried to post a picture but I haven't got enough reputation =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First button"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Second"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No, it's like the button SECOND only starts from the middle of FIRST BUTTON. So in your picture, SECOND would be a little more shifted to the right, so that its left edge is aligned with the center of FIRST BUTTON.